# Add to the Cart Button doesnt works on Firefox

Tags: opencart

Add to the Cart Button doesnt works on FF

I press the button and nothing happens , on chrome works fine

:-\ 
my web

goo.gl/g4vVwq

Answer (score 1):

use firebug in firefox to debug websites!
the first error is :

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mercadogamer.cl/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/external/jquery.cookie.js

i dont know if thats the error, but you better start there and fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Add this jquery.cookie.js jquery library file in catelog/view/javascript/ folder.
and change add the right url in to common header tpl.